# After changing aspect ratio of mp4 file, thumbnail in dolphin file manager still has incorrect aspect ratio

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails, aspect-ratio

I use the command:

```
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c copy -aspect 16:9 "${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

It creates a new file with the correct aspect ratio, but the new thumbnail of the new file still has the incorrect aspect ratio.

What can I do to get a correct thumbnail?

Comment: The thumbnail is likely cached. Did you check `~/.cache/thumbnails/` or whichever directory Dolphin uses? If there's an image for the video, delete it. Let me know if that helps and I'll add that as a reply.

Comment: Thank you Destroy666. I did what you wrote but the newly created thumbnail is again 4:3 instead of 16:9..

Comment: Perhaps that file manager doesn't support that aspect ratio then - check its settings, maybe there's something. Unfortunately I don't use that so I can't help further.